# shorter way to check a .pgn non case sensitive extension in bash

Tags: bash, uppercase, lowercase

I am writing a bash program that searches for .pgn (portable game notation) files in a folder. But in my program, .pgn extensions are not case sensitive. It means that they could be either lowercase or uppercase or a combination of the two. (.Pgn, .PGN, .pGn, .etc).
So for checking the extension I do this :

```sh
extension="${file: -4}"
extension="${extension,,}"
if [ "${extension}" == ".pgn" ]
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this, in a shorter way. By shorter, I mean do it all in the `if` statement.
Thank you in advanced for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash and a regex:

```
if [[ "$file" =~ \.[Pp][Gg][Nn]$ ]]
```

Or output content of `$file` in lowercase and then compare only with lowercase:

```
if [[ "${file,,}" =~ \.pgn$ ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You use already used the right syntax , but may be the wrong version of bash

if `bash --version` is 3.* the substitution `extension="${extension,,}"` is *NOT VALID*

`extension="${extension,,}"` is work with bash >= 4

```
for F in Aa.png  Ab.PnG  ; 
do 
    extension="${F: -4}" ; 
    extension="${extension,,}" ; 
    echo $F : $extension ; 
done
```

*alternative 1* : use `tr`  to lower your extension

```
extension=$( echo "${extension}"| tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" )
```

*alternative 2* : use `find` with `-iname`

```
find . -iname '*.pgn'
```

a example of loop

```
for F in $( find . -iname '*.pgn' -print );
do 
    echo $F;
done
```

*alternative 3* : use a regex to match the extension ( thanks to @Cyrus )

```
if [[ "$file" =~ \.[Pp][Gg][Nn]$ ]]
```

*alternative 4* : change the behavior of bash by setting the option `nocasematch`  ( thanks to @chepner )

`shopt -s` to enable   `shopt -u` to disable

a example

```
file="a.PGn" ; 
shopt -s nocasematch;  
if [[ $file = *.pgn ]]; then
    echo "PGN file"; 
fi; 
shopt -u nocasematch;  
if [[ $file = *.pgn ]]; then
   echo "PGN file";
fi;
```

Comment: Thank you for this in depth explanation. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nocasematch` option with simple pattern matching. There's no need to extract the extension.

```
shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $file = *.pgn ]]; then
    echo "PGN file"
fi
```